# How to get the date diff (duration) of a pull request merge commit?

Tags: git

I wish to see the number of calendar days between the first and last commit of my pull request merges. I am doing the below but wondering if there is an easier way to source this information:

First I get the commit hashes for all pull requests from `git log`:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%h|%an|%s" --merges | grep -i "my-name.*pull request" | cut -d'|' -f1
```

Then I loop through each merge commit hash and fetch the first and last dates of the commits in that PR like so:

```
git log --date=short $H^..$H --pretty=format:"%ad" | sed -e 1b -e '$!d'
```

Where `$H` is the commit hash from the previous output. The `sed...` extracts the first and the last line from the output.

Thereafter I compute the difference to get a duration in calendar days for my PRs.

This seems to be rather clunky and was wondering if there was a better way to source the *duration* of each of my PR merges. Does Git have anything to alleviate the pain or this is the best I can do?

Comment: This is functionally the same, in terms of collecting Git information anyway, as getting the specific commit hash IDs, which you can do with `git rev-list`. Once you have the IDs, you can use `git log --no-walk --format=%at` on the two endpoints, and subtract the resulting numbers to get elapsed seconds. It's worth thinking about the fact that these dates are easily spoofed, though, and what you're really looking at is the commit DAG, which doesn't necessarily match up with the actual PRs. It should be fine for your purposes though.

Comment: @torek: Can you please help me understand what is the similarity with `git rev-list`? Also are you suggesting that after I have my two commit hashes to use the `git log` with `%at`?

Comment: Hm, well, let's see ... your stackoverflow/other-sites profile suggests that you've been studying computing. Presumably you've done graph theory. What both `git log` and `git rev-list` do is walk a DAG. The DAG is composed of commits. These commit nodes store the IDs of their predecessors (plural for merge commits, singular for ordinary commits, dead-ends for root commits). It's a pretty standard and common graph except that the arcs all go *backwards* (because commits are immutable, and the graph grows over time).

Comment: The big difference between log and rev-list is the purpose of the graph walk: with `git log` it's to show something about each traversed commit, with `git rev-list` it's just to print the hash IDs (node numbers). Your existing `git log` command traverses your selected graph subset and prints out times with `%ad`; you then pick the first (which is the last) and the last (which is the first, at least with --topo-order; I'll get back to this in a bit) and then do your work with the date stamps. I'm suggesting, use rev-list for the graph walk and just print the hash IDs, then ...

Comment: ... then use the first and last hash IDs with `git log --no-walk` (suppressing the graph walk part) to convert the two date-stamps of interest, but use `%at` to get it as a Unix timestamp. You can then subtract the two to get elapsed seconds. You'll use more processes to gather the two timestamps (rev-list + log), but have easier computation to do the subtraction and less junk to toss out.

Comment: Now, the `--topo-order` comment: when traversing the DAG (backwards, as Git does by necessity), both log and rev-list use a priority queue. The queue is seeded from the starting commit you give the command; `git log` will use `HEAD` if you don't provide a starting point, while `git rev-list` demands a starting point. They then loop until the queue is empty: pop front of queue, print it, push selected parent(s) onto queue. Stopping points (as in `git log A..B`, which means `git log ^A B`) preclude commits from going into the queue if they precede or equal the supplied stop(s) (here, `^A`).

Comment: If `A..B` induces a purely linear subgraph, because nothing along the walk from `B` back to `A` has more than one parent, then this visits commit B, then B's parent, then its grandparent, etc., in order: the queue depth is always 1 or 0. But if there are *merges* in this subgraph, the queue depth reaches 2 when we reach a merge commit and push both its parents into the queue. At this point the priority aspect of the queue takes hold. The default priority is by committer timestamp: the higher the stamp, the closer the commit is to the front of the queue.

Comment: In your particular case, you probably *don't* want `--topo-order` since you'd like the *oldest* commit to come out last, regardless of which leg it might be on, in any merge. But you should think about how you want this all to behave in the presence of merge commits within your `A..B` range. Remember, too, that this is by *committer* timestamp, not *author* timestamp; `%ad`/`%at` prints the *author* timestamp. Each commit has two timestamps: use `git log --pretty=fuller` to see both.

Comment: @torek - this is useful. I hadn’t used `rev-list` until now and I think I got the idea. I need to be cognizant of the timestamp but I can get a decent start with this. Thanks.